# Google Spreadsheet API: Fetching specific Column

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to fetch specific columns from Google Spreadsheet by providing column headers. There are ways to fetch columns by setting `min-col` and `max-col` values [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#fetching_specific_rows_or_columns) but here, my set of columns should be continuous.

Eg: My spreadsheet has `id`  , `name` , `age` and `address` and I need to fetch `name` and `address` from all rows. How do I do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Query example is here, (ListDemo.java) gives SQL style access to the spreadsheet:

[How to query a Google spreadhseet via spreadhseet api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153290/how-to-query-a-google-spreadhseet-via-spreadhseet-api-v3)