# How to share a spreadsheet using Java Google Doc API

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I have successfully uploaded a spreadsheet to my GDrive.

Now i want that Document to be shared with specific email.
Can anyone give me some `tips` or some `code snippet` to achieve this Java.

Thanks Rohith.

Comment: Is this a REST client, or are you using the google drive api?

Comment: I think this help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153290/how-to-query-a-google-spreadhseet-via-spreadhseet-api-v3

Comment: @Justin I am using Java Google Drive API.

Comment: @Rohith Thanks, I think my answer should cover it. With the merging of Google Docs and Drive I may have slightly misunderstood the question, I'm not sure if the Google Docs API alone allows sharing or if the Google Drive API is needed now. Either way, the resources I've referenced should be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share a file, just give the user read permissions.
[This](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) describes how to add permissions to a file using either a REST client, or the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)

You can also see more details about sharing and permissions here: [Manage Sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing)

Comment: below is the code i am using to upload a file,  
how to find the file of uploaded file ?  
  
  `URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
DocsService docService = new DocsService("Doc");
docService.setUserCredentials("email@gmail.com","password");

DocumentListEntry uploadFile = new DocumentListEntry();
uploadFile.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("FileName"));
uploadFile.setFile(new File("/path/test.csv"), "text/plain");
uploadFile = docService.insert(feedUrl, uploadFile);`

Comment: @Rohith Better to create a new question.